# How do I put my 3D view back to normal, how it is by default?

Tags: interface, 3d-view

[image: 3D view in quad view]

How do I fix it back to when you first downloaded Blender?

Answer (score 9):

You have enabled the ***Quad View***. To get back to the 3D view press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> while your mouse hovers over the 3D viewport to toggle the quad view.

Another option would be to press <kbd>N</kbd> and then in the new menu scroll down to "Display" and click the button labeled "Toggle Quad View".

Answer (score 1):

In the top right hand corner of each panel there should be a group of lines (the same ones you used to make multiple panels) and drag it towards the panel you want to remove, should look something like this: [image: Delete unwanted panels]

If this isn't working for you, then you can press `CTRL-N`to reload the startup file, which should revert Blender to the original look. Unless of course you have modified the default startup file.

In which case you can press load factory settings. [image: load Factory settings]

This will also remove any personal settings that you changed. However, it is a last resort for changing blender back to default.

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Although this is correct, the user has activated *Quad View* which cant be restored by merging editors

Comment: Ah, my bad. Didn't see that.