# My object becomes skewed when rotating cameras position

Tags: objects, 3d-view, edit-mode

I'm pretty new to blender.  Picked it up and put it down numerous times before.  But I don't remember it ever doing this.

Whenever I try to rotate around my object to view it from different angles, the object becomes skewed in the viewport.

I know that this is strictly just a distorted view (and not a transformation of the object) because when I bring it back to "front view" the object looks fine.

Does anyone know whats up with this and how to get it to stop doing that?

thanks so much. [image]

Comment: Okay.  Hold on. never mind.  I think I figured it out.   I'm suppose to use keypad number 5 for the orthographic mode. That seems to have fixed what I was talking about.

Comment: The object is distorted. It is prefectly  possible that it looks straight from front view, but when looking at it from the side it shows distortion. For such a simple object just start over. Also you might want to learn about Quad view, where you can see the object from multiple views at once. Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81001/how-do-i-put-my-3d-view-back-to-normal-how-it-is-by-default/81003#81003